# Convert HTML line break into python dictionary

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I am scraping incident data from the RFS (Rural Fire Service) website to do some data analyse, However part of the data I get back i need to break it up to be more granular.

I have collected the following straight from a JSON and would appreciate some suggestions on how i could turn this 

`'description': 'ALERT LEVEL: Not Applicable <br />LOCATION: Turnbulls Lane, Moruya, NSW 2537 <br />COUNCIL AREA: Eurobodalla <br />STATUS: Out of control <br />TYPE: Structure Fire <br />FIRE: Yes <br />SIZE: 0 ha <br />RESPONSIBLE AGENCY: Fire and Rescue NSW <br />UPDATED: 3 Apr 2020 21:14'`

into this

```
{'ALERT LEVEL': 'Not Applicable', 'LOCATION': 'Turnbulls Lane, Moruya, NSW 2537', 'COUNCIL AREA': 'Eurobodalla', 'STATUS': 'Out of control', 'TYPE': 'Structure Fire', 'FIRE': 'Yes', 'SIZE': '0 ha', 'RESPONSIBLE AGENCY ': 'Fire an
d Rescue NSW', 'UPDATED': '3 Apr 2020 21:14'}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if the first key will not have any `:` in them, the following code should work

```
text = """'description': 'ALERT LEVEL: Not Applicable <br />LOCATION: Turnbulls Lane, Moruya, NSW 2537 <br />COUNCIL AREA: Eurobodalla <br />STATUS: Out of control <br />TYPE: Structure Fire <br />FIRE: Yes <br />SIZE: 0 ha <br />RESPONSIBLE AGENCY: Fire and Rescue NSW <br />UPDATED: 3 Apr 2020 21:14'"""
lines = text.split("<br />")
data_dump = {}
for line in lines:
    line = line.replace("'","")
    key,value = line.split(":", maxsplit=1)

    data_dump[key] = value
print(data_dump)
```

But this approach might break, if there was a `:` in the key of the text.

Comment: This works great cheers, lets just hope there never a `:` in the key lol

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data you retrieved is in Python JSON or otherwise dict-like format, try

```
split = data['description'].split('<br />')

d = {}

for x in split:
    key, val = x.split(': ')
    d[key] = val.strip()
```

Comment: This will break, when you have more than 1 ':' in the line. Check your output for UPDATED: 3 Apr 2020 21:14'

Comment: @Kris - note the whitespace in the second `.split()`. The timestamp won't be caught by that.

Comment: What I meant was, the : pattern can repeat, with or without white-space.  As I mentioned in my answer, my code too will break, if the key itself had a :